# How to test a single call within a method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

In the following code, I'd like to test that if `config_dir` doesn't exist, it is created.

```py
    def __init__(
        self, config_dir: pathlib.Path = pathlib.Path().home() / ".config" / "moe",
    ):
        """Read configuration.

        Args:
            config_dir: Path of the configuration directory.
        """
        self.config_dir = config_dir

        if not self.config_dir.exists():
            self.config_dir.mkdir(parents=True)

        self.db_path: pathlib.Path = self.config_dir / "library.db"

        # initialize db
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///" + str(self.db_path))
        library.Session.configure(bind=engine)
        library.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  # create tables if they don't exist
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to just test that part of the code. I've tried

```
    def test_config_dir_dne(self, mocker):
        """We should create the config directory if it doesn't exist."""
        fake_path = mocker.Mock()
        moe.config.Config(fake_path)

        fake_path.mkdir.assert_called_once_with(parents=True)
```

But, pathlib doesn't like that I use the specific join operator with the mock.

```
>       self.db_path: pathlib.Path = self.config_dir / "library.db"
E       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Mock' and 'str'
```

Also, I don't really care about that part of the code for this test, nor do I wish to create the engine at the end.

How can I just test check that `mkdirs` is called on my `fake_path` without running any of the other code?

Comment: What is `mocker`? Assuming you are using `unittest.mock`, use `MagicMock` instead, so that your instance supports the necessary magic method, `__truediv__`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained. it's just a namespace used by `pytest-mock` for `unittest.Mock`. This indeed fixes that error, but I think the question still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three general approaches here:

1. Mock out more.  Specifically, you could patch out `pathlib.Path` and `sqlalchemy.create_engine` and everything else that you don't want to test.
2. Use dependency injection so you can mock without patching.  Have the constructor take abstract interfaces and then have your test pass in dummy versions of those.
3. Restructure your code so that each unit you want to test on its own is its own function.  Take the logic that you want to test (the creation of the config dir), put that into its own function, and then unit-test that function independently of your constructor.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. Are any of the methods more favorable than the others? #3 sounds like I'll have a bunch of unnecessary functions sprinkled everywhere. I also worry that if I add any logic to my `__init__` method, then I also have to go back and adjust all my unit tests, but I suppose that can't be avoided.

Comment: I'd probably do a combination of #2 and #3 -- split the code that depends on the db from the code that doesn't so they can be tested separately, and dependency-inject the db functions to make testing of that part easier.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional argument to `__init__`, the function used to initialize the database. By default, you'll use a function supplied by the class itself.

```
def __init__(
    self,
    config_dir: pathlib.Path = pathlib.Path().home() / ".config" / "moe",
    db_initializer=None
):
    """Read configuration.

    Args:
        config_dir: Path of the configuration directory.
    """
    self.config_dir = config_dir

    if not self.config_dir.exists():
        self.config_dir.mkdir(parents=True)

    self.db_path: pathlib.Path = self.config_dir / "library.db"

    if db_initializer is None:
        db_intializer = self._init_db

    db_initializer(self.dp_path)

@staticmethod
def _init_db(p):
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///" + str(p))
    library.Session.configure(bind=engine)
    library.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

When you test the function, you'll pass a do-nothing function instead.

```
def test_config_dir_dne(self, mocker):
        """We should create the config directory if it doesn't exist."""
        fake_path = mocker.Mock()
        moe.config.Config(fake_path, lambda p: None)

        fake_path.mkdir.assert_called_once_with(parents=True)
```